# Missing return in a function

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, return

It's a simple question. As you can see in the code, there is return in every case. But , somehow, xcode does not recognizes the return in the `refresh()`'s `completionHandler` block.

Any suggestions?

```
    func accessTokenWithBearer() -> String {
            if !didTokenExpire() {
                return "Bearer \(accessToken!)"
            }else{
                Token.refresh({
                    return "Bearer \(self.accessToken!)"
                })
            }
    }

    class func refresh(completion: ()->()){
        completion()
    }
```

Comment: The `return` inside the `Token.refresh` is returning from the block, not the function.  A function can't return a value from inside the completion handler of an asynchronous call.

Comment: I see. Then how can I wait refresh block to end and then return the token?

Comment: Have your function take a completion handler as a parameter just like the `refresh` function does and call it instead of returning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment mentioned, you should add a completion handler to the `accessTokenWithBearer` function.

```
func accessTokenWithBearer(completion: String -> ()) {
    if !didTokenExpire() {
        completion("Bearer \(accessToken!)")
    }else{
        Token.refresh({
            completion("Bearer \(self.accessToken!)")
        })
    }
}
```

You could also have both a completion handler and a return value.

```
func accessTokenWithBearer(completion: String -> ()) -> String? {
    if !didTokenExpire() {
        return "Bearer \(accessToken!)"
    }else{
        Token.refresh({
            completion("Bearer \(self.accessToken!)")
        })
        return nil
    }
}
```